# Can we create clustered index with include columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can we create a clustered index with include columns in Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL)?

If yes then how does it work internally?

As per my understanding the leaf level of the clustered index are the actual data pages itself, and it stores entire row include with the key column (on which index is created).

Comment: By definition a clustered index includes all columns... so there are none left to include.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot specify included columns in a clustered columnstore index. From [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-2017):

> Nonkey columns can only be defined on nonclustered indexes

The reason for this is that when you apply a clustered columnstore index to a table, SQL Server changes the physical storage of the table to columns. As such, *all* columns are included in the clustered columnstore index.

Comment: Although your answer is not wrong, Dale Burrell's comment is much closer. The clustered index well keep the full rows physically sorted. In other words: It *is* the table itself. The conclusion: All columns are included implicitly. Other indexes will use this as *look-up* key.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo I've updated the answer to be more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure this applies--the question was about clustered indexes, not clustered _columnstore_ indexes.